# Number of watches in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs-scope

How can we calculate the number of watches in our angularJS application and maximum how many number of watches should be there in the single page?

Comment: Please show some tried code or what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you can use `ng-stats` to get the number of watchers. Or you could add their script in developer console for the tab and monitor the changes in their console. Its pretty much easy to use and integrate. [ng-stats](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats)